# Infinite Metric space, limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that in every infinite metric space, there exists an infinite sequence $(x_n)_1^{\infty}$ where no limit point of the set $S = \{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ is an element of the sequence.

Thoughts on how I might try to approach this? I tryed it directly and got no where since I'm not able to think of such a sequence.

Comment: By "infinite"  do you mean "unbounded" (in the sense that, given any $N>0$ there are two points in your metric space with $d(x,y)≥N$)?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @lulu By infinite I mean the space $X$ does not have a finite number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there is an $x\in X$ with the property that for each $B_{1/n}(x)$, there is an $x\neq x_n\in B_{1/n}(x)$. Then clearly the sequence $S=\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ and the claim is true since $x\neq x_n$ for any $n$.

Now suppose that there is no $x\in X$ for which the above property holds. Then for each $x\in X\quad \exists N_x\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\left \{ x \right \}\cap B_{1/N_x}=\left \{ x \right \}$. Then if $n\geq N_x$ we have $\left \{ x \right \}\cap B_{1/n}=\left \{ x \right \}$. i.e. $x$ is an isolated point of $X$. Hence no point of $X$ can be a limit point of any sequence of points in $X$.

So if the property holds, the claim is true; and if it does not the claim is true vacuously.